# How to create a popup window inside the dialog box?

Tags: android

I am creating one custom dialog box. It contains lot of folders and files. When click a Folders and/or Files to view the pop-up window inside the custom dialog box. How to create pop-up window inside the dialog box? I have no idea. If it is possible or not?

Comment: If you use `DialogFragment`s (be it either the HoneyComb+ or support lib version) it is definitely possible. In fact, it'll just be like adding another `(Dialog)Fragment` on top of what's already visible. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your custom dialog as normal Activity, and then in Manifest set the

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

for that activity. Now from your custom dialog, which is actually activity, you can show your popup dialog.